# Remove column with seed data EF Core Code first

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I am developing a project with .Net core, ef core and code first. The project contains several migrations, lets say for an example we have the next list of migrations:

```
Migrations/
     Initial
     Second
     Third
```

In the initial migration contains new tables, new columns, relations.... and some seed data for some tables.

For example:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'initial') 
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [Master].Colors (
        [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
        [Name] nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
        [HexadecimalValue] nvarchar(6)  NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_Colors] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
        )
END;

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'initial')
BEGIN
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Master].Colors ON;
        INSERT INTO [Master].Colors ([Id], [Name], [HexadecimalValue])
    VALUES 
        (1, N'Red', 'fff12'),
        (2, N'blue', 'fff12'),
        (3, N'yellow', 'fff12');
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Master].Colors OFF;
END;
```

But in the third migration, I need to drop for example [HexadecimalValue] column. Migration script generated:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'third')
begin
    ALTER TABLE [Master].Colors DROP COLUMN [HexadecimalValue];
END;
```

Everything seems to be OK, and if you run those queries examples you wont have any problem. The problem is when you run it more than once. When my release pipeline deploys again and again a new version, my script throws an error because there is no "[HexadecimalValue]" column, and Sql Server check if all objects exists no matter even if the query is not going to be executed (Notice the if statements, generated because --idempotent attribute).

The only 2 solutions i know are:

- Update previous migrations, removing seed data for that column. (updating autogenerated code :( )
- Updating my build, and play with -from -to ef core attributes (restrict version deployments :( )

Any other idea?

Comment: The `__EFMigrationsHistory` table should keep track of what migration the database is on and only execute the necessary migrations. Can you check the content of this table and see if the latest migration is mentioned?

Comment: Thask Jay Fridge but, the `__EFMigrationsHistory ` table has all migrations perfectly good. That´s not my problem. Try and check yourself those 2 scripts, try executing them more than once, and you will understand my problem.

Comment: It seems like this is an issue within .NET Core [#12911](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12911). The fix for this won't be included in 3.x but there are a few workarounds mentioned in the issue.

Comment: Thank you Jay!! That is exactly what is happening to me.